# Child is not being inserted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing difficulties with saving objects with jpa repositories. I have two entities. One to one related:

```
@Entity(name="USER")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long userId;
private String username;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Wallet wallet;
```

and the Wallet

```
@Entity(name = "WALLET")
public class Wallet implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "WALLET_ID")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Paper> papers;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

I have the issue with this situation - hibernate is not saving the wallet when I'm adding new user:

```
public String addUser(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
userDto.setUsername(userName);
WalletDto walletDto = new WalletDto();
userDto.setWalletDto(walletDto);
userService.addUser(userDto);
return userDto.toString();
}
```

and the addUser:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addUser(UserDto userDto) {
userRepository.save(userConverter.convertToEntity(userDto));
}
```

where save is jpa method.

EDIT:

```
  public void addUser(UserDto userDto) {    
            User user = userConverter.convertToEntity(userDto);
            Wallet wallet = walletConverter.convertToEntity(userDto.getWallet());
            user.setWallet(wallet);
            userRepository.save(user);        

    }
```

and really strange thing:

```
12:30:06,619 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.private.model.Wallet{id=6, papers=null, user=com.private.model.User#7}
12:30:06,619 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.private.model.User{username=xyzasew, userId=7, wallet=com.private.model.Wallet#6}
```

and in Wallet table there is no user trail = )

Edit. Almost there I hope = ):

[image: diagram]

I want wallet to be the master of user and paper, accordingly to Your advices I've eddited a bit entities:

```
@Entity(name = "WALLET")
public class Wallet implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "WALLET_ID")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Paper> papers;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "wallet")
private User user;
```

and user:

```
@Entity(name="USER")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long userId;
private String username;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Wallet wallet;
```

however wallet still does not have the user_id, and the user got it!

Comment: In your `userConverter` - do you set the both parts of the association?
I.E. do you set the `wallet.user` to your `user` instance?

Comment: well - no, but how can I set the wallet where there is no Id [ because not yet saved ]?

Comment: just set the reference. In your mapping wallet is the owner of association, not use. Or move the mappedBy from user to wallet

Comment: check the update of addUser, however now there is new insert in the Wallet table, but no id of user. Of course I can set it, but I thought that hibernate is doing it for me, when I map it properly. Have I done it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mappedBy` basically means i am not the owner for the `relationship`, `key` is on the other side. Putting `mappedBy` on both side means nobody is the owner of the relationship.

**Theoretically**

Using `"mappedBy"` attribute of mapping annotations(like `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`) for `bi-directional relationship`. This attribute allows you to refer the associated entities from both sides. If "X" has association with "Y" then you can get X from Y and Y from X.

`MappedBy` signals hibernate that the key for the relationship is on the other side.

The annotation `@JoinColumn` indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship. That is, the corresponding table has a column with a foreign key to the referenced table, whereas the attribute `mappedBy` indicates that the entity in this side is the inverse of the relationship, and the owner resides in the "other" entity.

**Practically**

```
@Entity
public class X implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="y_fk")
    public Y getY() {
        ...
    }

@Entity
public class Y implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "y")
    public X getX() {
    ...
}
```

Since this is annotated with `mappedBy` it shows that this is NOT the owner, and that the Owner is X (the field that is annotated). name attribute is telling Hibernate where to find the information about the `FK` mapping (inside `X` there is a `getY()` method). No additional fields will be created in Y.

**Improvements to be done in the above code**

**@LazyCollection:**

> defines the lazyness option on @ManyToMany and @OneToMany
>   associations. LazyCollectionOption can be TRUE (the collection is lazy
>   and will be loaded when its state is accessed)

**User.Java Entity changes can be reduced to below**

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Wallet wallet;
```

Comment: I've done the thing, but still no USER_ID in the wallet table, however the insert have been done in both tables

Comment: + User has now three fileds: user_id, username, wallet_wallet_id and bidrectional relationship with Wallet. I wanted Wallet to have walle_id, user_id and paper_id. I messed up a bit!